# Parsing source file and trying to get its methods doesn't work. Why is it not working?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"C:\Users\Umut\source\repos\frmMain\Program.cs");
        var tree = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
        var methods = tree.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();

        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(method.Identifier);
        }
    }
```

I have this code and I am trying to read the methods out of the source code. When I run it with this:

```
foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(method.Identifier);
        }
```

it's not working. Console just shows nothing (well, except for the press any key text). So it does compile but doesn't print out anything. Can anyone explain me why?

EDIT: I am just stupid. I am using parsetext on a file, I needed ParseFile and have to use it like that:

```
    var path = @"C:\Users\Umut\source\repos\frmMain\frmMain1.cs";
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(stream), path: path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just stupid. I am using parsetext on a file, I needed ParseFile and have to use it like that:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Umut\source\repos\frmMain\frmMain1.cs";
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(stream), path: path);
```